# How do you do the multiplication of an infinite sided regular polygon by an infinitesimal side to get the perimeter of it?

Tags: calculus, infinity, pi, polygons

Using the law of cosines to find each side length and multiplying by the number of sides, I see a pattern, which should approach $~2\pi~$ as the number of sides grows to infinity.

How can $~2\pi~$  be calculated, when it's infinity multiplied by an infintesimal?

Using the law of cosines, the missing side of each perimeter section can be found, where $~x~$ is the number of sides the polygon has.  In this, the distance from each vertex on the polygon to the center $~= 1~$ unit.

The formula for each polygon's perimeter based on its number of sides $(x)$ is as follows:

perimeter $= x * \sqrt{2 - 2 ~\cos\left(\frac{360}{x}\right)}~.$

So, what is $~2\pi~$ , using this infinite by infinitesimal product?  Calculus anyone?

Answer (score 4):

Using Taylor series for large $x$

$$\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{x}\right)=1-\frac{2 \pi ^2}{x^2}+\frac{2 \pi ^4}{3
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$
$$2-2\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{x}\right)=\frac{4 \pi ^2}{x^2}-\frac{4 \pi ^4}{3
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{2-2\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{x}\right)}=\frac{2 \pi }{x}-\frac{\pi ^3}{3 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$
$$x\sqrt{2-2\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{x}\right)}=2 \pi -\frac{\pi ^3}{3 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$

Use it for $x=6$; the exact perimeter is $6$ for sure and the above formula gives
$2 \pi -\frac{\pi ^3}{108}\approx 5.99609$.

If you want a still better approximation, using Padé approximants,
$$x\sqrt{2-2\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{x}\right)}=2 \pi -\frac{20 \pi ^3}{3 \left(20 x^2+\pi ^2\right)}$$ which, for $x=6$, would give $5.99997$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\text{If}\;\,&
f(x)
=
x
\sqrt{
2-
2\cos
\bigl(
{\small{\frac{2\pi}{x}}}
\bigr)
}
\\[12pt]
\text{then}\;&\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x))^2\\[8pt]
&=
\lim_{x\to\infty}
x^2
\left(
2-
2\cos
\bigl(
{\small{\frac{2\pi}{x}}}
\bigr)
\right)
\\[8pt]
&=
4\pi^2\lim_{x\to\infty}
\frac
{
2-
2\cos
\bigl(
\frac{2\pi}{x}
\bigr)
}
{
\left(\frac{2\pi}{x}\right)^2
}
\\[8pt]
&=
4\pi^2\lim_{t\to 0^+}
\frac{2-2\cos(t)}{t^2}
\\[8pt]
&=
4\pi^2\lim_{t\to 0^+}
\frac{\sin(t)}{t}
\qquad\text{[by L'Hopital's Rule]}
\\[8pt]
&=
(4\pi^2)\,(1)
\\[8pt]
&=
4\pi^2
\\[12pt]
\text{hence}\;&\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=2\pi
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}